# Merging Plot with the same scale in gunplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am having some troubles getting the desired results when using Multiplot with a specified size and margins. I have attached a picture shows the issue when plotting my data. I am interested in merging plots with the same scale. For that I specified `xsize= 0.40, ysize= 0.90, and xinit= 0.10` as in the code below. When the data files were plotted, the y-axis of the right plot was a bit lower than that of the left plot. If I was not looping, everything seems to work as expected. I even tried to move `xsize= 0.40, ysize= 0.90, and xinit= 0.10` inside the for loop but no luck.

```
set term png
xsize= 0.40   
ysize= 0.90  
xinit= 0.10   
do for [i=1:files] { 
set output sprintf("Picture(x=-%d).png",i) 
set multiplot layout 1,2

# Reset keys
unset rmargin
unset lmargin
# Set individual keys

set size xsize, ysize                  # Plot size in relation with canvas
set lmargin at screen  xinit           # x inital possition 0.10
set rmargin at screen  xinit + xsize   # x final possition 0.50 
set  xlabel "x[m]" offset 2,0          # Displace xlabel to the center of canvas
set  ylabel "y[m]"

plot filename(i) using 4:3 with lines notitle

# Reset keys
unset rmargin   # Clears the past x position
unset lmargin
unset label     # Clears the past label
unset ytics     # Removes the y axis tics
unset ylabel    # Removes the y axis label

set size xsize, ysize                  # Plot size in relation with canvas
set lmargin at screen  xinit+xsize     # x inital possition 0.50
set rmargin at screen  1 - xinit       # x final possition 0.90 

plot filename(i) using 6:3 with lines notitle 
unset multiplot
}
```

[image]

I wonder what could be the issue in my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the different heights in the sub-plots.
Have you tried `reset session` at the beginning?
Is this really the plot you're getting with above code? Where are the axes labels and the data? For a minimal example you just can insert `plot x` or something else.
Which gnuplot version and operating system are you using?

Comment: Hi Theozh, thanks for your help. I am using gnuplot 5.0 on a Unix environment. reset session doesn't seem to work thought I found help to rest parameters.

Comment: Problem solved or still open? Your script does not produce the output you show.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case you should use the `spacing` and `margins` options for multiplot:

```
set multiplot layout 1,2 margins 0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05 spacing 0,0
```

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks for the help. Is there anyway to keep what I have above? If you remove the for loop and use it to plot one data file, everything would look pretty good. If you use `xsize= 0.40   
ysize= 0.90  xinit= 0.10` inside the loop for each plot and change only `ysize= 0.90` to `ysize= 0.974` for the second plot, they would look identical. Is this a bug in gnuplot?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in your case. And I don't know why you want to keep it so complicated.